# I want to start animation of svg path at my selected point in svg path

Tags: animation, svg

I have some issue with SVG animation. I want to start animation from my selected point in the SVG path. Right now my animation starts from upper side middle. but I want to start animation from the left or right side middle of the circle.
is there any technique to select the animation starting point?
Below is my pen where you can see my code.

```
<div class="step-1-wrapper steps ">
  <div class="step-1-inner">
    <div class="step-1-icon-wrap anim-step-1" >
        <svg class="circular-chart orange step-1-circle">
        <line stroke-dasharray="5, 5" x1="250" y1="255" x2="330" y2="255" class="step-1-2-line-mvr"></line>
        <line x1="250" y1="255" x2="330" y2="255" class="step-1-2-line-mvr-anim"></line>
        <path class="circle-bg" d="M165 170
        a 85 85 0 0 1 0 170
        a 85 85 0 0 1 0 -170"></path>
        <path class="anim-circle" d="M165 170
        a 85 85 0 0 1 0 170
        a 85 85 0 0 1 0 -170"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.steps {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: -2px;
    margin-left: -2px;
}
.step-1-icon-wrap {
    height: 155px;
    width: 155px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(26,122,171,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(26,122,171,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(26,122,171,0.25);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.circular-chart {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: -57px;
    top: 3px;
}
.anim-circle {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #f8fcff;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}
.anim-circle {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #f8fcff;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}
.circle-bg {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #57c1f8;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-dasharray: 6;
}
.step-1-2-line-mvr {
    stroke: #57c1f8;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
.step-1-2-line-mvr-anim {
    stroke: #f8fcff;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}
.anim-step-1 .step-1-2-line-mvr-anim {
    animation: dash 3s linear 1.5s normal 1;
}
.anim-step-1 .anim-circle {
    animation: dash 3s linear 1s normal 1;
}


.step-1-inner{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 430px;
    padding-top: 180px;
}


@keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    } 
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }
}
```

[my SVG animation pen](https://codepen.io/awesome_designer/pen/xaKeOr)

Answer (score 0):

I'll show some possibilities for the animation starting at the right quarter point. It should be obvious how to change them for the left point.

#### 1. Rotate the circle around its center

```
<path class="anim-circle" transform="rotate(90 165 255)" d="M165 170
    a 85 85 0 0 1 0 170
    a 85 85 0 0 1 0 -170"></path>
```

#### 2. Start the path at the right quarter point

```
<path class="anim-circle" d="M250 255
    a 85 85 0 0 1 -170 0
    a 85 85 0 0 1 170 0"></path>
```

#### 3. Animate correct `stroke-dasharray` lengths

You are working with rule-of-thumb values for the length of the path. That, by the way, leads to insufficient control over how long the animation actually takes. It's not complicated: Your circle has a radius `r = 85`, so the circumference is `2π × r ≃ 534`.

(For the nitpickers: In theory, you can define an artificial length for a stroke with the [`pathLength`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathLengthAttribute) *attribute*, but it's not implemented in Safari.)

`stroke-dasharray` works like this: it is a list of numbers, each denoting alternatingly the length of a stroke and a gap. There is no reason why you shouldn't animate this list instead of the `stroke-dashoffset`, which can remain at the quarter-circle position.

```
.anim-circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 534;
    stroke-dashoffset: -133.5; /*move the start of the stroke by one quarter*/
}

@keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 534 0; /*all stroke*/
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0 534; /*all all gap*/
    }
}
```

(You had me a moment before I noticed that you are *obscuring* the blue path with a white stroke - and that you had erroneously doubled the CSS rule for `.anim-circle`.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. it will be the great help to me. I used it and working fine.